# Recover Code Behind Files from a App_Code.dll

Tags: asp.net, recovery

I lost my solution files for a project which I've sent to my web host earlier. Now I need to edit and fix some but I don't have the solution files now. I have my project with App_Code.dll.

Is there a way to get the whole project back ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) together with [the FileDisassembler plugin](http://www.denisbauer.com/NETTools/FileDisassembler.aspx). This combination can generate a visual studio solution file.

And make sure to implement proper source control from now on!